# How to change default email id "hello@example.com" (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, configuration, smtp

### How to change "hello@example.com" (Magento 1.9)

I have installed the extension **SMTP pro**.

After running "self test" of the extension, it displays following error

```
         SMTP Pro Self Test Results : 
        Sending test email to your contact 
from address: hello@example.com 
from: [My_Email_id_Here] Unable to send test email
```

Now how do I change this default email id "helloworld@example.com" ?

Comment: Please go through SMTP Pro documentation first before posting a question here. If you cant just google it, I did that for you. Please find the link http://ecommerce.sunovisio.com/media/blfa_files/Sunovisio_Smtp_Extension_3.4.0_.pdf .

Comment: Please note third party questions are out of scope questions here because it's codes are not available.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Change emails here]

Changing email addresses here in store email addresses and contacts will fix the issue.

Comment: if this fixed, please feel free to accept the answer.