# How to combine Register and Login forms (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer, login, register

### How to combine Register and Login form (Mangeto 1.9)

I am trying to merge fields of Registration form

from the template

**persistent/customer/form/register.phtml**

to the template

**persistent/customer/form/login.phtml**

But the copid fields **(from register.phtml)** are not getting displayed in **login.phtml**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<reference name="content">            
    <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml">
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml" />            
    </block>
</reference>
```

by this u can put html where do u want to place in customer/form/login.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer_form_register') ?>
```

Comment: Sure. Min 8 mins are required by stack. You can check my profile. As a fresher I have put many basic questions, you can answer them also.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143481/how-to-change-default-email-id-helloexample-com-magento-1-9 for this what is your store email id

Comment: helloworld@example.com

Comment: You want to remove  helloworld@example.com right

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to remove that helloworld@example.com and I want the extention to send mail from **my_email_id@gmail.com**

Comment: Then you change store email id to your email id(my_email_id@gmail.com)

Comment: it's working.....